# How to use Green's Theorem to find area bounded by two curves?

Tags: calculus, greens-theorem

Just starting out for calculus but are you able to help explain how to use Green's Theorem. How to fins the area bounded by the curves:

$x = a\cos^3{t}, y = a\sin^3{t}, (0 \leq t \leq 2\pi)$

How do I use the theorem for this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take in Green's formula $P=0, Q=x$ or/and $P=-y, Q=0$ and obtain
$$S=\int_\limits{\partial G^+}xdy=-\int_\limits{\partial G^+}ydx=\frac{1}{2}\int_\limits{\partial G^+}(xdy-ydx)$$
Can you finish from here?